# Alignment of accessoryView when using multiline contentView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a fairly simple TableViewController listing items that can be checked as they are collected.  I have successfully implemented a word wrapped label in each cell, and updated heightForRowAtIndexPath such that each row is a suitable height.  This is working well:

note: I have set a garish background color on the cell's contentView for testing purposes.

[image]

The problem comes when I try to add a checkmark button as the accessoryView for each cell:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
```

For some reason, the alignment is not quite right for my cells that span more than one line once the button size exceeds about 26x26 pixels.

[image]

The example above uses 44x44 as the button width.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?  Why would there be a different alignment when the contentView is 2-lines versus one?  Infact, for each extra line that the text uses, the alignment is increasingly off.  I can add the code for the row text if it will help.

Comment: Additional info - I have determined that it is the HEIGHT of the frame that causes the problems, not the width.  If I set it to 44 x 26 it looks ok.  Over 26 and it's misaligned.

Comment: Did you try to set your button's `autoresizingMask` accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this can be resolved by setting the height of the button in the accessory view to match what will be calculated for the row.

So, the code used in heightForRow:atIndexPath: should be copied in to the cellForRowAtIndexPath and used to set the button's height.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and unfortunately I neither can explain the odd behaviour, nor did I solve it. But I made some observations that may be help to others struggling with this issue.

I am using a `UIImageView` as an accessory view for my cells, and ended up fiddling around with the image dimensions. What finally worked were images to a size of about 16x16 pixels or lower.

As I just wanted a rather tiny image, this worked for me.